# Problemas com hotkey para abrir e esconder a interface usando "Application.Current" (C# WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, app

O seguinte código funciona sem problema fiz ele com base no código disponível na internet do SirMestre, porém ele só abre/fecha a UI MainWindow, já tentei algumas coisas para funcionar mas da erro ou não funciona nas outras UI's.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Threading;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Threading;    

namespace Model.Libraries.KeyBoardHooking
{
    public class KeyBoardHooking
    {
        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        private static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(Key vKey);
        [DllImport("User32.dll")]
        private static extern short GetAsyncKeyState(int vKey);

        public KeyBoardHooking()
        {
            Thread Thread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    // tecla abrir/fechar (PgUp)
                    if (GetAsyncKeyState(33) == -32767)
                    {
                        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() =>
                        {
                            if (Application.Current.MainWindow.Topmost == true)
                            {
                                Application.Current.MainWindow.Hide();
                                Application.Current.MainWindow.Topmost = false;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Application.Current.MainWindow.Show();
                                Application.Current.MainWindow.Topmost = true;
                            }
                        }));
                    }
                    Thread.Sleep(1);
                }
            })
            {
                IsBackground = true
            };
            Thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            Thread.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Funcionamento desse código é bem simples, aperto PgUp ou a tecla que eu configurar no "GetAsyncKeyState" que ele abre/fecha a UI, quando eu altero o "MainWindow" para "Window1" que é outra UI na aplicação ele retorna um erro falando isso: **"Application" não contém uma definição para "Windows1" e não foi possível encontrar nenhum método de extensão "Widnows1" que aceite um primeiro argumento do tipo "Application".**
(Nisso que da ficar pegando code na net hehehe).

Comment: Como assim altera o "MainWindow" para "Window1"? Coloca o que o você tentou fazer

Comment: `Application.Current.MainWindow.Hide();`
para 

`Window1 window1 = new Window1`
`Application.Current.Window1.Hide();`

Comment: Ainda está muito confuso a utilização do seu código. Não consigo entender qual é o objetivo. Você quer que toda vez que pressionar uma tecla especificamente (nesse caso PgUp) esconda ou exiba toda a aplicação? Apenas uma janela especifica? Como você está instanciando a classe `KeyBoardHooking`? Mais informações...

Comment: `using Model.Libraries.KeyBoardHooking;

public MainWindow() {
            DataContext = this;
            InitializeComponent();
            new KeyBoardHooking();
}`

Nesse caso ele já entra no laço `While(true){}` e fica sempre verificando no if se a tecla foi pressionada, caso pressionada, ele vai pro segundo if  onde ele verifica se o aplicativo está no Top, caso verdadeiro ele oculta a aplicação, caso falso ele mostra a aplicação.

https://gist.github.com/ruidevs/a80afcb9ea83ca3e6f7260d1f1c6f7e3

Comment: O que eu gostaria de fazer, porém não funciona é fazer o mesmo com a outra Janela, chamada Window1, porém quando altero o "MainWindow" para Window1 lá do segundo **if** do `KeyBoardHooking` , ele retorna o seguinte erro: **"Application" não contém uma definição para "Windows1" e não foi possível encontrar nenhum método de extensão "Widnows1" que aceite um primeiro argumento do tipo "Application".**

https://imgur.com/GLt72do

Answer (score 0):

Vamos lá Guilherme,

O que acontece é que você está interpretando errado a static class `Application` e consequentemente a propriedade `Current`.

> Application.Current.Window1.Hide();

Esta utilização está errada. Não existe a propriedade `Window1` em `Application.Current`.

Para resumir, quando cria uma instancia, devera utilizar a instancia criada. Exemplo:

```
Window novaJanela = new Window(); //instancia criada.
novaJanela.Hide(); //executa o método Hide
```

**SOLUÇÃO**

Método `KeyBoardHooking` corrigido

```
public KeyBoardHooking()
        {
            StatusViews Window1 = new StatusViews();

            Thread Thread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    // tecla abrir/fechar (PgUp)
                    if (GetAsyncKeyState(33) == -32767)
                    {
                        Application.Current.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(DispatcherPriority.Background, new Action(() =>
                        {
                            if (Window1.Topmost == true)
                            {
                                Window1.Hide();
                                Window1.Topmost = false;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                Window1.Show();
                                Window1.Topmost = true;
                            }
                        }));
                    }
                    Thread.Sleep(1);
                }
            })
            {
                IsBackground = true
            };
            Thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            Thread.Start();
        }
```

Espero que ajude. 
Abraços...